# cudamat test exception: error initializing CUBLAS

Tags: nvidia, python, cuda

I've installed nvidia drivers ,cuda and cudamat. When I run test_cudamat.py, It gives me this exception:

```
cudamat.CUDAMatException: error initializing CUBLAS: (err=-2)
```

I tried adding libcublas.so directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but nothing changed.

Installing nvidia driver from ".run" file had ruined everything. So I reinstalled ubuntu, installed it from xorg-edgers ppa and now "About This Computer" shows my GeForce graphics and everything looks fine.
Then I installed cuda 5.5 with the same method.

The package didn't provide cuda samples and I can't access nvidia.com because of government sanctions.
So I can give you the samples' result if I find them in some ppa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok...

Installing nvidia-331-uvm fixed it. It was not included in nvidia-331 and nvidia-cuda-toolkit.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-uvm
```